# Angularjs Impedir a entrada de urls sem dados

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um problema, quero fazer uma página que pegue valores que determinei em um arquivo video.js ser retornado a uma url específica.

```
.state('video.id', {
url: '/:id',
templateUrl: 'tpl/video_id.html',
})
```

Sendo o paramentro **:id** o valor que tenho que digitar no navegador para puxar os dados específicos do arquivo video.js e retornar ao site.

Isso está sendo feito. No entanto, ele também tenta retornar valores sem mesmo ele existir, podendo abrir a página, mas não havendo nenhum registro, podendo até mesmo, ser aberta sem registro algum.

exemplos:

**site.com/video/** - abre mas nao mostra nada

**site.com/video/LALALALA** - abre mas nao mostra nada, pois não existe esse id no arquivo, se existe aparecia.

Como posso bloquear a entrada da página, quando não existir os valores de id no arquivo?

Comment: Quando for feita a busca pelo id, caso não exista, você pode redirecionar para outra página, `video-404.html`, por exemplo

Comment: Como fazer isso? realmente não penso em nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você precisa verificar

1. Se o id existe
2. Se o ID é valido

Para depois redirecionar se um dos dois caso for falso.

Levando em consideração que você está usando o [Ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference):
Seria algo assim:

```
init();

function init(){
  var isValidId = funcaoParaValidarId($stateParams.id);

  if(!$stateParams.id || !isValidId){
    $state.go(404);
  }

}
```

Referência:

[$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

[$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service)

Comment: Obrigado pelas referências! consegui pelo seu metodo